# using Do Until to find specific text in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, find, excel-formula

I need to enter a formula to extract a portion of text from specific cells. This needs to be repeated an unknown number of times. I am using a do statement with the find function. Unfortunately it will only find the first occurance and loop continously. Is there a way to force finding the next value?
Can anyone help me?

Here is the code I am using:

```
    Do

    With Columns("B")
        .Find(What:="total", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
    End With

     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],12)"
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],12)"



    Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Grand Total"


    End Sub

Thank you for your assistance.
jfabro

I have been able to make the macro work to loop through the entire workseet however it does not stop when the condition is met. I believe the problem lies in the condition. What I am needing to say is to stop if the cell to the right of the active cell contains Grand Total.

Here is the new code I am using:
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "*Grand Total*"

With Columns("B")
    Cells.Find(What:="total", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End With

 ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],12)"
 Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "*Grand Total*" Then


Exit Do

End If

Loop





End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like you probably should just change the `.Cells(1,1)` reference to use index variables that increment each time you run the loop.  Probably something like `.Cells(index,1)` (...stuff in loop...) `index = index + 1`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx shows how to use `Find` in a loop.

Comment: That helped Tim however now it runs through the entire file 2 times before an error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your string match, I'd replace:

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "*Grand Total*" Then


Exit Do

End If
```

with:

```
If Instr(1,ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).value,"Grand Total")<>0 then Exit Do
```